# condition to check whether any element has a specific class

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript loop that contains a conditional statement.
I need the condition to check whether the current item in the loop contains any element with a specific class name.

*This is what I currently have, however as you'll see this is not correct.
Currently my condition checks whether the current element has a specific class name, HOWEVER, I need it to check whether ANY element inside the element has a specific class name.*

```
selectionList.forEach(selectionItem => {
    if (selectionItem.classList.contains('myclass')) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I'm editing this post because it seems that people are misunderstanding.
I just need help with the following line in my code:

```
if (selectionItem.classList.contains('myclass')) {
```

The above checks whether the current element has a specific class name, but I need it to check whether the current element contains any CHILD element with a specific class name.

Comment: `// do something` could be `some_boolean = true`. Then if condition `some_boolean` later

Comment: Can you elaborate what `I need it to check wheather ANY element inside the element has a specific class name`? Do you mean that you also want to check the child elements of `sectionItem`?

Comment: @Kiran I edited my question, and clarified

Comment: Okay, so you need to run another loop inside your loop. Something like ```currentElement.currentElementChildren.forEach(() => {})```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.querySelector(selector)` to search for children of some `element`.

`!!element.querySelector(selector)` will return `true` if it finds something matching `selector` inside that `element`, and will return `false` otherwise.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.outer');

elements.forEach(el => {
  let hasChildren = !!el.querySelector('.searchClass');
  console.log(`${el.classList[1]} has children with .searchClass: ${hasChildren}`);
});
```

```html
<div class="outer outer-1">
  <div class="inner searchClass"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer outer-2">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer outer-3">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner searchClass"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop, just call [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the class name passed in (prefixed with a `.`) on the element you wish to examine to return a collection of all the elements that contain that class. You can check the resulting collection's `.length` to see how many elements were found and you can loop over the collection (with `.forEach()`) to enumerate them individually.

```js
// Find every element that has the myclass class and put them in a collection
let matchingElements = document.querySelectorAll(".match");

let count = matchingElements.length; // Count how many there are

// Loop over the collection
matchingElements.forEach(function(element){

   // Do whatever you want with the current element being enumerated
   console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="needsChecking">
  <p>something</p>
  <p class="match">bingo</p>
  <a href="#">stuff</a>
  <div>
    <div class="match">bingo
       <h1 class="match">bingo</h1>
       <h2 class="nomatch"></h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="needsChecking">
  <p>something</p>
  <p class="match">bingo</p>
  <a href="#">stuff</a>
  <div>
    <div class="match">bingo
       <h1 class="match">bingo</h1>
       <h2 class="nomatch"></h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="needsChecking">
  <p>something</p>
  <p class="match">bingo</p>
  <a href="#">stuff</a>
  <div>
    <div class="match">bingo
       <h1 class="match">bingo</h1>
       <h2 class="nomatch"></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not what I'm looking for. I don't think you understood correctly. I absolutely need the loop. My loop gets a bunch of elements from my page with a specific class, then the loop needs a condition that will run code if the current loop element contains any children with a specific class name.

Comment: @Shtarley then you should not put the loop inside question at first place. it distract from actual question.

Comment: @Shtarley My answer does exactly what you are asking for. You start with the collection of elements that have a particular class (just like what you state above) and then call `.querySelectorAll()` on that collection. No loop is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Element.querySelector(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) or either [`Element.querySelectorAll(selector).length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) in order to check if there is a child with the given selector:

```js
yourElements.forEach(element => {
    if (element.querySelector(yourSelector)) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
})

// if there is no "something different" to do would be like this
yourElements.filter(elem => !!elem.querySelector(yourSelector))
  .forEach(element => {
      // do something
  })
```

In your case could be something like

```js
selectionList.forEach(selectionItem => {
    if (selectionItem.querySelector('.myclass')) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**children**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property.

See my snippet below, I've included some notes.

```js
//get parent element
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
//get children
var children = parent.children;
//run a loop and check if children have a specific class name
for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  if (children[i].classList.contains('child1')) {
    //log the children with class name child1
    console.log(children[i])
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child1"></p>
  <p class="child1"></p>
  <p class="child2"></p>
  <p class="child3"></p>
</div>
```